# Opening new sessions of R equivalent to using foreach dopar?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

Will opening 4 sessions of R and running scripts at the same time be as efficient as using the foreach dopar with 4 cores?

Comment: Different sessions cannot share RAM. If your analysis is based on big objects, keep in mind that each session must have a copy of the objects. In one parallelized session, you don't have this issue.

Comment: Ok thanks, I won't need to share RAM